# Spring JDBC MVC project gives 404

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've been fighting with the Spring framework for few weeks now, and I got
a normal MVC page to show up, and I got JDBC to print onto the console.
But I can't seem to get these to work together...

I've been through countless tutorials at this point and every one of them
seem to have some type of error or problem.

I think I've finally managed to get together a pretty decent and working build, but nope, still getting only 404's.

I think the problem might be in the spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="src" />
```

And I'm not sure if you can even load project like that, but it's the only thing I can think of here.

I include all the other files too, though.

#### Console Errors

```
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-mvc' did not find a matching property.
```

and

```
SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/spring-mvc] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4903)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring-mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.gatein.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>common-logging</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- Telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
 <context:annotation-config />

 <!-- Declaring base package -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

 <!-- Adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Declare beans -->
 <bean id="userDao" class="dao.UserDaoImpl" />
 <bean id="userService" class="services.UserServiceImpl" />

 <!-- Declare datasource bean -->
 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="38613861" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>SpringJDBCTemplate</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### homePageController

```
package controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import domain.*;
import services.*;

@Controller
public class HomePageController {

 @Autowired
 UserService userService;

 @RequestMapping("/register")
 public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {

  List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<String>();
  genderList.add("male");
  genderList.add("female");

  List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
  cityList.add("delhi");
  cityList.add("gurgaon");
  cityList.add("meerut");
  cityList.add("noida");

  Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
  map.put("genderList", genderList);
  map.put("cityList", cityList);
  return new ModelAndView("register", "map", map);
 }

 @RequestMapping("/insert")
 public String inserData(@ModelAttribute User user) {
  if (user != null)
   userService.insertData(user);
  return "redirect:/getList";
 }

 @RequestMapping("/getList")
 public ModelAndView getUserLIst() {
  List<User> userList = userService.getUserList();
  return new ModelAndView("userList", "userList", userList);
 }

 @RequestMapping("/edit")
 public ModelAndView editUser(@RequestParam String id,
   @ModelAttribute User user) {

  user = userService.getUser(id);

  List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<String>();
  genderList.add("male");
  genderList.add("female");

  List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
  cityList.add("delhi");
  cityList.add("gurgaon");
  cityList.add("meerut");
  cityList.add("noida");

  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("genderList", genderList);
  map.put("cityList", cityList);
  map.put("user", user);

  return new ModelAndView("edit", "map", map);
 }

 @RequestMapping("/update")
 public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
  userService.updateData(user);
  return "redirect:/getList";
 }

 @RequestMapping("/delete")
 public String deleteUser(@RequestParam String id) {
  System.out.println("id = " + id);
  userService.deleteData(id);
  return "redirect:/getList";
 }
}
```

#### Project tree

[Project tree from Eclipse Neon2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke0uQ.png)

Comment: Do you use the m2e maven/eclipse plugin? Is this project imported as a maven project? At least for me, Maven had everything come in under `src/main/java/<my>/<package>/<name>` rather than just src. Also, any reason you're using xml config instead of java config?

Comment: how are you running your app?

Comment: @artemisian right click -> run as server (tomcat9) i also have separate linux server with tomcat9 which i use to deploy without eclipse, neither one works.

Comment: Can you post an image of the structure of the war file when you create it, run 'mvn package'. The war file can be opened by a file compressor/decompressor app as WinRar.

Comment: @S.Buda i have the plugin and this project was written by me from tutorial, not imported. I just didnt think the packages when i wrote it so now i dont know what to use but "src" No particular reason for xml other than trying to get any of these goddamn things to work atleast once...

Comment: @Clomez, don't worry will try to help you. As a side note, if you want to save some headaches you can try sometime spring-boot, it does a lot of auto-configuration for you and you can download working copies: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: I suspect that your problem lies on a configuration you added on the build section of your POM, since maven project works with WEB-INF structure rather than WebContent. Remove the maven-war-plugin from your plugins and test again. Let me know.

Comment: Looked at your structure image now, and it seems odd to me since a war project in maven doesn't create this kind of structure. It seems it was a dynamic web project that was converted to a maven project. So you can do following test to see if it works: copy only POM.xml and src folder to a new folder create another workspace, and import it as a maven project, not eclipse nor web project

Comment: This is a proper structure for an maven web project: https://conorpower.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/maven-project-structure.png and in webapp folder it should have WEB-INF and resources foder

Comment: @JorgeCampos you are correct, it's a dynamic project converted to maven, i really have no clue how i should properly do this and i just cant find any clear explanation for it. How should i redo this project? Also i removed maven-war plugin but that didnt help

Comment: There seems to be tons of tutorial, all doing things little differently and i just cant get any of them to work. if anyone have any clear tutorial about getting mvc project to show mysql data with maven and eclipse on jsp page, that would be nice.

Comment: So, lets make it right then...

Comment: follow these steps: 1 - Create a folder a new folder anywher lets call it [mvnproject]; 2- Create the structure in the image in my previous comment **except** the target folder; 3- copy your pom.xml to the root of mvnproject folder; 4- go to your physical project structure in the folder src copy all folders `controller, dao, etc` to the new structure in mvnproject/src/main/java

Comment: 5 - copy the WEB-INF folder of your project into the mvnproject/src/main/webapp; 6 - remove the lib folder (you don't need it since maven will handle the dependencies)

Comment: 7 - in a new eclipse workspace, import a new project selecting a existing maven projects and select the mvnproject path. 8 - after import the project click on it and press ALT + F5 (pc keys) this will tel eclipse to update maven dependencies and that should do it

Comment: Next steps will be to configure a apache tomcat server to deploy your project into

Comment: This is the basic, and if you still have problems with it, try this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/ this guy have the easiest tutorials to follow and he always add the project code at the end.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you, very much. I will try that but it takes some time, i'll get back to you. but thank you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos well, it now looks like this, i thinks its right but still not working. http://imgur.com/a/zijjV

Comment: @Clomez Well, that looks more right to me, at the very least. And your frustration pretty sums up my experience getting spring to start. It's always a headache creating a new project but once things are running it works nicely.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.... It still not right. I know that because Eclipse should not show the package as `main.java.controller....` Maven ignores that folder and start right under the java folder as it was the src folder itself. Someting must be wrong on your project. Try cleaning everything, remove the project from eclipse, delete (physically) the folder .settings and the file .classpath and the file .project. Go on your folder project on the console and run `mvn clean eclipse:clean` then open all folders of if (like the image I showed to you) and paste it here so I can see what it is wrong

Comment: This is how a maven web project structure in eclipse should look like: http://imgur.com/dRHDo9u I'm using the package explorer view in eclipse

Comment: Well, i got it to work but i had to rebuild the whole thing, eitherway mega thanks to @JorgeCampos for your help, atleast i now understand better whats going on, cheers!

Comment: Great to hear that. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my answer but the one which solved the case, posting as answers since it's buried deep in comments.

> Sorry for the delay.... It still not right. I know that because
>   Eclipse should not show the package as main.java.controller.... Maven
>   ignores that folder and start right under the java folder as it was
>   the src folder itself. Something must be wrong on your project. Try
>   cleaning everything, remove the project from eclipse, delete
>   (physically) the folder .settings and the file .classpath and the file
>   .project. Go on your folder project on the console and run mvn clean
>   eclipse:clean then open all folders of if (like the image I showed to
>   you) and paste it here so I can see what it is wrong

**– Jorge Campos**